# SQL Server 2008 Copy Database Wizard: Fail

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to use the SQL Server 2008 Copy Database Wizard to copy a SQL Server 2008 database. I am using the SQL Management Object method. 
However, the copy fails with the following error:

```
ERROR : 
errorCode=-1073548784 description=Executing the query "/* 
'==============================================..." 
failed with the following error: "Cannot use a CONTAINS or 
FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view 'Product' because 
it is not full-text indexed."
```

Any ideas on how I can proceed with this will be super helpful

**EDIT**

The background to this question stemmed from trying to move a database that is in restore/stand by mode (it is the log shipping destination db). This seems to be the only viable channel (not a hack) without breaking the logshipping chain?

Kind Regards
Nai

Comment: Here's a question on SO that is strikingly similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527878/sql-server-2008-copy-database-wizard-fail. Maybe you can get going on the right track from that.

Comment: he and i are having the same problem essentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule #1 is that the database copy wizard sucks.  It is probably trying to create your stored procedures before it creates the full text indexes.  Take a backup of the database and restore it to the other system.

Comment: That's the feeling I got because a few SPROCS that were referencing tables that were not longer used were flagged before that halting the entire operation. 

See the thing is, I am really trying to move a database that is in restore/stand by mode (it is the log shipping destination db) and this seems to be the only viable channel without breaking the logshipping chain? Do you have any workarounds for this?

Comment: If you are trying to move the log shipping destination you'll need to take a full backup and restore that full to the new destination so that you can startup the log shipping again.  You won't be able to copy the database using the copy database wizard and then change the log shipping to point to this destination database (if that's what you are trying to do).